# Callback after Login() of ADAL.js is not called in Edge

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am using [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)(which calls Azure Active Directory) as javascript library for verifying the user. I am using the following code for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.15/js/adal.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var endpoints = {
            "https://management.core.windows.net": "https://management.core.windows.net"
        };
        var config = {
            clientId: 'e333d3fe-a73a-4476-8121-8a57f9a972ca',
            endpoints: endpoints,
        };
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
        authContext.handleWindowCallback();

        function onSuccessLogin(error, token, msg) {

            console.log("Inside Call back");

            if (!!token) {
                console.log("Log-in to Azure successfully done", token);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error while log-in to Azure", error);
            }

            if (!!authContext._user) {
                console.log("You are connected to Azure ")          
            }
        }

        function login() {
            authContext.popUp = true;
            authContext.callback = onSuccessLogin;
            authContext.login();
           // authContext.handleWindowCallback();
            var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
            console.log(user);
        };

        function logout () {
            authContext.logout();
        };

    </script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="clickme()" />
    <input id="Button3" type="button" value="login" onclick="login()" />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="logout" onclick="logout()" />

    // These are the text-boxes whose value I want to retain.
    First name:<br>
    <input id=fname" type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input id="lname" type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
</body>
</html>
```

These are few issue with this code in Edge, although everything is working fine in chrome:

1. Why the onSuccessLogin() is not always called on edge?
2. Why the pop window for log-in is not appearing always?
3. Sometime after entering the credential the pop won't close.

Comment: I found this [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/Known-issues-on-Edge) which defines this issue and workaround too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is:

- set the `config.callback` and `popUp=true` before calling AuthenticationContext(config)

Also you should not call handleWindowCallback() if the URL does not contain a #. The code should be:

    `if (authenticationContext.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
        authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();`

I suggest that you have a look and adapt the following sample I tested and worked in Edge (and of course Chrome) in both cases (with and without popup):
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof-ca/blob/master/TodoListSPA/app.js
(the configuration is in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof-ca/blob/master/TodoListSPA/appconfig.js)

Comment: I have checked the sample link and done exactly as you have suggested. Now, the things are working fine in edge for logged-in user. But in private window of edge, the callback is never called. The pop won't close and the url of pop-up become : https://localhost:44315/#id_token=eyJ0eXsV1cQiLPCJhxbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsI........................

Comment: Yes, there are known issues with Edge (not due to the library): local and session storage is lost when you’re redirecting across zones while in InPrivate. Edge are working on fixing their storage in a future release. In the meanwhile, you can workaround the issue by removing the redirect across zones by making sure both the refer and redirected sites are in the same zone.

Comment: Its not even working in non private windows of edge.

Comment: I found this [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/Known-issues-on-Edge) which defines this issue and workaround too.