# ADAL4 Angular 7 - How to handle login error

Tags: angular, adal, adal.js

I have an Angular 7 application & I am using adal-angular4 library to login. I wanted my entire application to be protected so I have guards on all the routes.
If I use valid credentials, everything works fine. If I use wrong domain credentials, it redirects back to the application & automatically redirected back to login screen.
How to capture login error & display the correct error message on screen for user.

The redirected URL has below hash content. How to capture & show an appropriate error message.

## error=invalid_grant&error_description=AADSTS500083:+Unable+to+verify+token+signature.+No+trusted+realm+was+found+with+identifier

In MSAL.js there are various events like, msal:loginFailure or msal:acquireTokenFailure which can be registered. I could not find similar events to register in ADAL.

Comment: ADAL also offers you the opportunity of handling events associated to the login outcome. For example: adal:loginSuccess, adal:loginFailure.

Comment: @AllenWu I see those events are available in AngularJS. I am using Angular 7. I tried to search about how to implement that with no results so far.

Answer (score 0):

In ADAL, the callback funtion which is invoked when logging is successful or failed is defined in the `callback` property of `AuthenticationContext` object. Refer to [Callback after Login() of ADAL.js is not called in Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032410/callback-after-login-of-adal-js-is-not-called-in-edge) for a sample.

The problem here is the library you use doesn't expose this property. So you have to update the library on your own to expose this property.

To make it easier, I would suggest you use the official MSAL Angular library: [@azure/msal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular). It provides callbacks for loginfailure or loginSuccess.

Note: to use MSAL Angular with Angular 6+, need to install `rxjs-compat`

Comment: First solution you provided is javascript version, not sure if I can use that in my angular 7 project & so far I am using msal itself, but the current version has lot of issues. With msal, I am getting timeout issue on acquiretoken call in Mac safari & IPad. That's why I am looking for other library.